# How do I set the background colour of the component with a class of card to the bgColour variable defined above?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Inside the if statement is a variable called bgColour and I want to set that to the background colour of the div with a class of card but I my attempts to access it have not worked. Can somebody tell me how to solve this? If there is a way to use a seperate css page to do this then that would be even better.

```
renderIssues2 = () => {
    let bgColours = ['Green', 'Yellow', 'Red'];
    let statusOptions = ['Available', 'Under Maintenance', 'Not Working'];
    return this.state.issues.length > 0 ?
        this.state.issues.map((issue, index) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < statusOptions.length; i++) {
                if (statusOptions[i] === issue.status) {
                    let bgColour = bgColours[i];
                }
            }
            return (
                    <div class="card" >
                        <div class="card-title">{issue.issues}</div>
                        <div class="card-body">{issue.message}</div>
                    </div>
            );
        })
        :
        null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the forLoop for determining the bgColour is redundant
- bgColour is `block scoped` inside the forLoop

```
    const { issues } = this.state;
    let bgColours = ["Green", "Yellow", "Red"];
    let statusOptions = ["Available", "Under Maintenance", "Not Working"];
    return issues.length > 0
      ? issues.map((issue, index) => {
          const colorPos = statusOptions.indexOf(issue.status);
          const bgColor = bgColours[colorPos];
          const style = bgColor ? {"backgroundColor": bgColor} : {};
          return (
            <div class="card" style={style}>
              <div class="card-title">{issue.issues}</div>
              <div class="card-body">{issue.message}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })
      : null;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an Object of status to colour mapping

```
const statusToColor = {
  'Available': 'green',
  'Under Maintenance': 'yellow',
  'Not Working': 'red',
};

renderIssues2 = () => {
  return this.state.issues.length > 0
    ? this.state.issues.map((issue, index) => {
        const bgColor = statusToColor[issue.status];
        return (
          <div class="card" style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }}>
            <div class="card-title">{issue.issues}</div>
            <div class="card-body">{issue.message}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    : null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you're assigning the variable `bgColour` a color value from your `bgColours` array but you're not using that variable when you render your card so that color is not being used anywhere.

Add the `bgColour` as a class to your card, then in a css file, maybe your main `index.css`, create classes for each of your colors.

```js
<div className={"card " + bgColour}>
   <div className="card-title">{issue.issues}</div>
   <div className="card-body">{issue.message}</div>
</div>
```

```css
.Green{
   background-color: green;
}
.Yellow{
   background-color: yellow;
}
.Red{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Also, in React when assigning class names, you need to use `className`, not `class`.
[Styling Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)